# Evaluating the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(xy)}{1+x^2+y^2}dx$ for all $y$.

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I have some difficulty with the following exercise:

Calculate $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(xy)}{1+x^2+y^2}dx$.

I tried to differentiate $\frac{\sin(xy)}{1+x^2+y^2}$ to simplify the integral, but the result seems to be more difficult.

I don't have any idea on how to solve this. Can anyone help me or give me a hint?

Comment: The integral depends on $y$. Is it really your willingness ?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net oh, still wish you a good evening =)) And yes, I think the answer is depended on y

Comment: The solution involves the [hyperbolic sine integral](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Shi.html) and [hyperbolic cosine integral](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Chi.html). Are you familiar with these functions? If not, then perhaps your integral should be
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\color{red}{\cos(xy)}}{1+x^2+y^2}dx$$
which has an elementary solution.

Comment: Some calculations show that $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(xy)}{1+x^2+y^2} \text{d}x
=\mathcal{P.V.}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-xy}}{1-x^2+y^2} \text{d}x$$The Right hand side is Exponential Integral $\text{Ei}(z)$.To arrive the final result,you should make some substitutions and take limits to $(y^2+1)_{-}$ and $(y^2+1)_+$.

Comment: @projectilemotion I have know hyperbolic sine and hyperbolic cosine but have never heard about shi and chi (their integral) before. I think I have to spare some minutes to look up and explore what it is. Can you help me if the integral is cos(xy) ?

Comment: If we have $\cos(xy)$ instead, one could use differentiation under the integral sign twice on the integral
$$I(a)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos(ax)}{x^2+b^2}~dx$$
and solve the ODE $I''(a)=b^2 I(a)$. Alternatively, see [How to solve the following integral? 4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1917253/how-to-solve-the-following-integral-4?noredirect=1) or [Evaluating an integral with Laplace](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/718912/evaluating-an-integral-with-laplace?noredirect=1).

Comment: As the resulting integral I get $\frac{\sin \left(y \sqrt{-y^2-1}\right) \left(\text{Ci}\left(y \left(x-\sqrt{-y^2-1}\right)\right)+\text{Ci}\left(y \left(x+\sqrt{-y^2-1}\right)\right)\right)+\cos \left(y \sqrt{-y^2-1}\right) \left(\text{Si}\left(y \left(x-\sqrt{-y^2-1}\right)\right)-\text{Si}\left(y \left(x+\sqrt{-y^2-1}\right)\right)\right)}{2 \sqrt{-y^2-1}}$ where Ci(x) is the Cosine integral and Si(x) is the Sine integral function.

Comment: Although the resulting integral function doesn't look very nice, I hope it helps a little. With the help of substitutions, one can certainly simplify the term.

Comment: The definite integral involves Meijer G function.

Comment: Correct - my flaw is that I considered the wrong range from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

Comment: Considering the correct range from $0$ to $\infty$, then I obtain the following function (and here as @ClaudeLeibovici mentioned the Meijer G function is involved): $\frac{\sqrt{\pi } G_{1,3}^{2,1}\left(\frac{1}{4} \left(y^4+y^2\right)|
\begin{array}{c}
 1 \\
 1,1,\frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)}{y^3+y}$. The following prerequisite condition must be true: $\Im(y)\leq 0\land \left(\Im\left(\sqrt{-y^2-1}\right)\neq 0\lor \left(\Re(y)=0\land \Re\left(y^2\right)+1>0\land \Im(y)+1>0\land \Re\left(\sqrt{-y^2-1}\right)\leq 0\right)\right)$.

Comment: @Zacky: I ran Mathematica and used the wrong range in the first trial. After changing it to the correct one I obtained a more compact term that involves the Meijer G function. In order to get a rough idea how these functions look like, I added some plots (the answer section allowed me to add figures). I hope these may help and support the investigations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the more general integral for variable $a>0$ and fixed $b>0$:
$$I(a)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(ax)}{x^2+b^2}~dx. \tag{1}$$
We will show that $I$ satisfies a certain ODE, and then solve it. First, note by integration by parts that
$$\begin{align*} I(a)&=\left[-\frac{\cos(ax)}{a(x^2+b^2)}\right]_0^{\infty}-\frac{2}{a}\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x\cos(ax)}{(x^2+b^2)^2}~dx\\&=\frac{1}{ab^2}-\frac{2}{a}\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x\cos(ax)}{(x^2+b^2)^2}~dx. \tag{2} \end{align*}$$
Thus it follows that
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x\cos(ax)}{(x^2+b^2)^2}~dx=\frac{1-ab^2I(a)}{2b^2}. \tag{3}$$
Note that $1/a$ is a common factor in equation $(2)$, so multiplying by $a$ and differentiating w.r.t. $a$ gives
$$\begin{align*} I(a)+aI'(a)&=2\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^2\sin(ax)}{(x^2+b^2)^2}~dx\\&=2\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(ax)}{x^2+b^2}~dx-2b^2\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(ax)}{(x^2+b^2)^2}~dx\\&=2I(a)-2b^2\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(ax)}{(x^2+b^2)^2}~dx. \end{align*}$$
Differentiating with respect to $a$ one last time and using equation $(3)$ gives
$$\begin{align*} I'(a)+I'(a)+aI''(a)&=2I'(a)-2b^2\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x\cos(ax)}{(x^2+b^2)^2}~dx\\&=2I'(a)-1+ab^2 I(a). \end{align*}$$
Simplifying gives the ODE
$$I''(a)-b^2 I(a)=-1/a. \tag{4}$$
We now proceed to solve this differential equation. We can do this using variation of parameters. A fundamental set of solutions for the homogeneous equation is given by $\{e^{ab},e^{-ab}\}$. The method results in the need to consider the [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral) $\operatorname{Ei}$ defined for nonzero real values of $x$ by
$$\operatorname{Ei}(x):=-\int_{-x}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}}{t}~dt.$$
The general solution can then be written as
$$I(a)=C_1 e^{ab}+C_2 e^{-ab}+\frac{e^{-ab}\operatorname{Ei}(ab)}{2b}-\frac{e^{ab} \operatorname{Ei}(-ab)}{2b}.$$
We now claim that $C_1=C_2=0$. Note that
$$|I(a)|\leq \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2+b^2}~dx=\frac{\pi}{2b},$$
hence for fixed $b$ we have that $I$ is bounded. Taking the limit as $a\to \infty$ and using [Proof of $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\operatorname{Ei}(x)}{e^x}=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1556396/proof-of-lim-x-to-infty-frac-texteixex-0?noredirect=1) and showing that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\operatorname{Ei}(-x)}{e^{-x}}=0$ proves that $C_1=0$. Finally, taking the limit as $a\to 0^+$ shows that $C_2=0$ since $\lim_{a\to 0^+} I(a)=0$. Therefore, the solution to the integral is (if you wish, you can generalize to $a,b\neq 0$ using the symmetry of the integrand)
$$I(a)=\frac{e^{-ab}\operatorname{Ei}(ab)}{2b}-\frac{e^{ab} \operatorname{Ei}(-ab)}{2b}.$$
Hence, it follows that for $y\geq 0$
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(xy)}{1+x^2+y^2}dx=\frac{e^{-y\sqrt{1+y^2}}\operatorname{Ei}(y\sqrt{1+y^2})}{2\sqrt{1+y^2}}-\frac{e^{y\sqrt{1+y^2}} \operatorname{Ei}(-y\sqrt{1+y^2})}{2\sqrt{1+y^2}}.}$$

---

**Note:** An alternative form for $I(a)$ is
$$I(a)=\frac{\operatorname{Shi}(ab)\cosh(ab)-\operatorname{Chi}(ab)\sinh(ab)}{b},$$
where $\operatorname{Shi}$ is the [hyperbolic sine integral](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Shi.html) and $\operatorname{Chi}$ is the [hyperbolic cosine integral](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Chi.html). Alternatively, one can write the result in terms of the [Meijer G function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MeijerG-Function.html) as written by @EldarSultanow.

Answer (score 1):

The searched integral function involves the [Meijer G function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MeijerG-Function.html) and it is given by:

$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(xy)}{1+x^2+y^2}dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } G_{1,3}^{2,1}\left(\frac{1}{4} \left(y^4+y^2\right)|
\begin{array}{c}
 1 \\
 1,1,\frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)}{y^3+y}$

where the following condition must be met:

$\Im(y)\leq 0\land \left(\Im\left(\sqrt{-y^2-1}\right)\neq 0\lor \left(\Re(y)=0\land \Re\left(y^2\right)+1>0\land \Im(y)+1>0\land \Re\left(\sqrt{-y^2-1}\right)\leq 0\right)\right)$

The plot of original function for $x,y\in[0,10]$ is:

[image]

and the plot of the resulting integrated function for $y\in[9,9.5]$ is:

[image]